# Why doesn't TEMPO react with itself?

Tags: organic-chemistry, radicals

TEMPO ((2,2,6,6-tetramethylpiperidin-1-yl)oxyl, or (2,2,6,6-tetramethylpiperidin-1-yl)oxidanyl) has the following structure:

[image: TEMPO structure]

Given that it's a free radical, why doesn't it react with itself, despite being capable of reacting with *other* radicals in the system itself)?

In addition, according to Wikipedia, it's a red-orange, sublimable solid. How can it be a solid despite being a radical?

Comment: _Everything_ can form a solid. Being or not being a radical is irrelevant here.

Comment: 1,1-Diphenyl-2-picrylhydrazide is a stable, purple, solid free radical.

Comment: You don't need a complicated or sterically hindered molecule.  Oxygen and the $\ce{NO_x}$ oxides are quite stable free radicals under typical ambient conditions.  Credit goes to molecular orbital structure, in both the radical and any supposed dimer.

Answer (score 22):

I believe the first part of your question is asking why the oxygen with the unpaired electron doesn't find a second one to form a peroxide.

The answer is actually quite simple. It is by design. Next to the nitrogen, you see the 4 methyl groups that give TEMPO the "TEM" part of it's name. These methyl groups give TEMPO a lot of steric bulk around the oxygen, and this bulk makes it very difficult for two TEMPO radicals to form an oxygen-oxygen bond with each other. There is just not enough space. You can build a model to convince yourself of this.

Comment: https://chemapps.stolaf.edu/jmol/jmol.php?model=CC1(C)CCCC(C)(C)N1OON2C(C)(C)CCCC2(C)C is a link to the 3D structure of the molecule formed from two TEMPO radicals.

Comment: It is definitely not only steric repulsion but also a lone pair effect. It is mostly that the formation of a NO-ON bond is quite unstable due to the lone pair repulsion which is larger than the energy gain of forming a sigma bond. (The same reason that peroxides are relatively unstable)

Answer (score 9):

Steric hindrance is the way to make them stable. 
I have never worked with TEMPO, but I have seen this one in our lab:

[image]

Here the steric hindrance is very evident. 
This is also a nice stable solid.

Comment: [You don't even need the chlorine substitution.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triphenylmethyl_radical)

Comment: @OscarLanzi Right, but the one I have seen making is with chlorine. Surprisingly easy: trichlorobenzene, chloroform and aluminium trichloride.

Answer (score 0):

The stability of TEMPO and hence is formation is thought to result from resonance involving the nitrogen lone pair as well as hyperconjugation from the numerous methyl groups. See also [the Wikipedia article on 3 center 2 electron bond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-center_two-electron_bond).

The resonance involves oxoammonium contributors as those postulates in oxidation catalyse by TEMPO and carbanions, hence invoking sacrificial hyperconjugation.

[image: Oxoammonium contributors in TEMPO]

As stressed in other answers the steric hindrance of the methyl groups *also* plays a major role "caging" the radical center and leading to longer than usual bonds when TEMPO reacts.

Consider that coupling two TEMPO would lead to a peroxide. Peroxides are, with few exceptions, unstable and reactive.

The above effects makes a hypothetical $\ce{O-O}$ bond in TEMPO even less stable than that one in other peroxides,  where it is already characterised by energy of about $\pu{50 Kcal/mol}$, i.e. less than the already unstable $\ce{O-H}$ bond in the same molecule and generally speaking less than a half of $\ce{C-C}$, $\ce{C-H}$ and $\ce{C-O}$.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75220/discussion-on-answer-by-alchimista-why-doesnt-tempo-react-with-itself).