# How to you show a 3-center 2-electron bond in a Lewis structure?

Tags: bond, notation

How would you write $\ce{PCl5}$ or other hyper-conjugate molecules as a Lewis structure that indicates 3-center 2-electron bonds?

I have seen depictions [[1](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Jennifer_Green6/publication/232225251_The_occurrence_and_representation_of_three-centre_two-electron_bonds_in_covalent_inorganic_compounds/links/0912f50811807999f5000000/The-occurrence-and-representation-of-three-centre-two-electron-bonds-in-covalent-inorganic-compounds.pdf?origin=publication_detail)] for transition metal complexes but not for main group non-metals such as sulfur or phosphorous.

Comment: With dashed lines but in some structures I am puzzled, too.

Comment: I started writing an answer, but realized I was rambling, and it was probably better as a comment. My opinion is that Lewis structures are too focused on 2-center-2-electron bonds to easily depict anything else. I feel like in practice, you draw everything as a electron pair and rely on reader experience to detect when things are 3-center-2-electron bonds.

Comment: I had troubles to convey 3c-2e in TEMPO (in conjunction with a big number of hyperconjugation mesomers) to explain the long life of it in an old threat. And still have them.

Comment: @Alchimista - TEMPO? Oh, I see: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/90993

Comment: As a general comment, it's clear that the conventions for Lewis structures that have accumulated over the years are are not internally consistent, but are so well-established that it's too late to change. For example, in second row oxides like $\ce{HNO3}$, octet rule wins over "minimize formal charge", but in the third row, expanded octet is preferred over adding formal charge, as in $\ce{H3PO4}$. For more complex bonding interactions like the two $\pi$ half-bonds in $\ce{O2}$, Lewis structures are completely inadequate.

Comment: If you stick to the original idea of Lewis diagrams, you are limited to 2e-2c bonds (no donor-acceptor-bonds, i.e. no arrows), and you should be. Then again, the concept of hypervalency is only necessary for these bonds, and a phosphorus bonded five times, or pi bonds within sulfate are fine. Since we know that is (at least partially) wrong, a different kind of representation has to be chosen, which must be more complex. @zhe said it best: rely on the experience of the reader, even when that makes it impossible for the beginner to understand. (meta: Ugh... a researchgate pdf, how ugly.)

Comment: There is an article in JChemEd suggesting a way to count electrons even in the presence of 3-center-2-electron bonds: https://doi.org/10.1021/acs.jchemed.9b00750

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What about the probably "not so good" approach might be the bent bond as sometimes seen for diborane?

[image]

([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diborane))

The latest *recommendation* by IUPAC I know, exemplified in rule "GR-1.9 Multi-center bonds":

[image]

([Brecher](https://www.degruyter.com/view/j/pac.2008.80.issue-2/pac200880020277/pac200880020277.xml), *Pure Appl. Chem.*, **80**, 277-410, 2008; doi 10.1351/pac200880020277, open access)

stating:

> "As a matter of convention, any such multi-center character is ignored
>   when producing chemical structure diagrams, and regular bonds
>   connecting pairs of atoms are used instead."

---

To accommodate Karsten Theis' comment on the initial form of this answer, I would like to add the perspective provided by Robert Grossmann's [*The Art of Writing Reasonable Organic Reaction Mechanisms*](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/b97257).  Starting page 270 (2nd edition, 2003) the chapter introducing reactions with transition metals draws attention about "Conventions of Drawing Structures"; highlighting that there *are* field dependent *conventions* about what line and dash represent.  To quote:

> "The conventions for drawing organometallic and inorganic compounds
>   differ in subtle ways from those used to draw “ordinary” organic
>   compounds. The most important difference is the way in which bonds are
>   drawn. In organic compounds, one does not use a line to connect a bond
>   to an atom. In organometallic and inorganic compounds, however, a line
>   sometimes connects an atom and a  $\sigma$ or $\pi$ bond. In this
>   case, the line indicates that the pair of electrons in the $\sigma$ or
>   $\pi$ bond is shared with the metal also."

[image]
(*loc. cit.* p. 271)

> "An even more confusing situation arises in complexes in which the
>   electrons in a $\pi$ system spread over three or more atoms are used
>   to make a bond to a metal. In this case, the usual convention is to
>   use a curved line to indicate the $\pi$ system and a single line to
>   connect the $\pi$ system to the metal, regardless of the number of
>   electrons in the $\pi$ system (the organometallic chemists’
>   convention). However, sometimes the curved line is omitted and single
>   lines are used to connect the metal to each of the atoms in the $\pi$
>   system (the crystallographers’ convention). The representation that
>   would make the most sense to organic chemists, in which a single line
>   represents a two-electron  bond and a dative bond is used to show
>   two-electron bonds between each individual $\ce{C=C}$ $\pi$ bond and
>   the metal, is simply never used."

[image]
(*loc. cit.*, p. 271)

> "Formal charges are usually omitted in inorganic and organometallic
>   complexes. Only the overall charge on the complex is indicated. For
>   example, formal charges are usually not assigned in Lewis acid–base
>   complexes involving transition metals. The acid–base bond is sometimes
>   indicated by an arrow pointing from the ligand to the metal, but more
>   often it is indicated by an ordinary line."

[image]
(*loc. cit.*, p. 271)

This precedes just the section about electron counting (specifically in organometallic compounds with transition metals). I speculate, however, Robert Grossman aiming to highlight differences between "organic" and "organometallic" convention meant `does` while accidentally deploying `does not` in the first paragraph.

Comment: For the diborane, if you count 2 electrons per line representing a bond, one structure has the correct electron count and the other (the IUPAC-preferred) doesn't. If you don't expect 2e-3c bonds, this might trip you up. I guess it's the same for coordination compounds.

Comment: @KarstenTheis  Thanks to your comment, the perspective provided by the answer was enlarged.