# What compound was drawn on this sidewalk?

Tags: aromatic-compounds, identification, nitro-compounds

A friend found this in the sidewalk of Kent town of Canterbury:

[image]

What compound is this, and why would its picture be there?

Comment: TNT aka trinitrotoluene.

Comment: Looks like a granite board with poorly drawn molecule of what would be TNT if not for weird $\ce{ON2}$ group. What symbol are you referring to, exactly?

Comment: @andselisk The entire compound: NO2, CH3, NO2, ON2, surrounding an O.  My last chemistry class was in 2009.

Comment: What is the connection with Kent town?

Comment: @BuckThorn No idea, really; there were several cryptic images like this in the sidewalk there of which he shared images.  For all I know it could be a Guy Fawkes reference, but I'm over the pond in "New England" so that's a guess out of the blue.

Comment: @andselisk: Nice catch. I'm sure caver didn't understand difference between $\ce{-NO2}$ and  $\ce{-ON2}$. Caver probably meant to go $\ce{O2N -}$, but seemingly lost in the transition! :-)

Comment: TNT had not been discovered around the time of Guy Fawkes, but looks like there's an answer posted with a good explanation....

Comment: Either this post should be fixed or closehammered. I mean seriously, calling chemical formula a "symbol"? Also "Simple question: what is it ?" isn't making it any favors.

Comment: @Mithoron Being much more familiar with mathematics and physics, my concept of a formula is a bit different, and I wasn't sure how to refer to what I know now is a "chemical formula".  I didn't want to confuse it with a "chemical equation", which I know now is something else different, indeed.  Anyway, not sure what "closehammered" is on StackExchange, or how to "fix" the post, but I do appreciate the feedback I've received, which has provided the insight I'd hoped when I added Chemistry to my Stack account.  Thanks, all !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Certainly, it's *meant* to be trinitrotoluene, TNT, with a "typo". Perhaps a craftsman tried to copy an image, such as that from Wikipedia, below, which shows the oxygen atoms outside the ring:

[image: TNT from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Trinitrotoluene.svg]

As to the *reason* for that sidewalk plaque:

Faversham, ~16 km from Canterbury, produced TNT, and [on April 2, 1916, some 200 tons of TNT exploded](https://www.kentonline.co.uk/kent/news/kents-forgotten-disasters-221902/), killing 115 people (apparently set off by other munitions -- it is rather difficult to detonate TNT alone). "News of the blast was kept secret due to the wartime sensitivities at the time. It is now recognised as the worst ever disaster in the UK explosives industry."

While there's a monument at the mass burial in Faversham, below, the plaque might be an additional memorial.

[image: TNT disaster victims' monument]

This is reminiscent of the [Halifax, NS, CA munitions explosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halifax_Explosion), December 6 1917. with "equivalent energy of roughly 2.9 kilotons of TNT", killing about 2,000.

**However,** it might also be a crafty advertisement, if in somewhat poor taste, for either:

- [TNT Improv and Sketch Comedy Society](https://improwiki.com/en/improv_group/tnt_improv_and_sketch_comedy_society) in Canterbury at University  of Kent
- [TNT Delivery](https://www.mbe.co.uk/canterbury/parcel/tnt)

Comment: There is an [entire book](https://www.amazon.com/Great-Explosion-Gunpowder-Anatomy-Disaster/dp/1844882810) about the disaster.

Answer (score 7):

The inner of the structure formula neither is a character, nor a number.  It is a Thiele ring (suggested by [Johannes Thiele 1865-1918](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johannes_Thiele_(chemist)) by 1899) to describe aromaticity, after Kekulé's approach already was disseminated.  It was an old practice (say up to about 1960s) you still may encounter in the electronic age, e.g.

[image]

when you neither want to draw one structure instead of the resonance structure on the very left, and the one on the very right, or because your sketcher program (ChemDraw, Chemdoodle, etc.) falls in this form.  Or, because you encounter such a drawing you want to assign a (kekulized) SMILES string:

[image]

(credit to both drawings: Noel O'Boyle, John W. Mayfield. We need to talk about... Kekulization, Aromaticity, and SMILES.  254th ACS National Meeting Washington, August 2017.  Archived on [Noel O'Blog](https://baoilleach.blogspot.com/2017/08/my-acs-talk-on-kekulization-and.html)).

*However*, because it represents recurrent potential pitfall when counting how many electrons actually are present, especially if chemists from different experience/with different convention in their mind meet each other:

[image]

(Robert Grossmann [The Art of Writing Reasonable Organic Reaction Mechanisms.](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/b97257), already used earlier [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/116519/how-to-you-show-a-3-center-2-electron-bond-in-a-lewis-structure/116526#116526))

especially in charged states (e.g., the assumed intermediate anions of Birch reductions), the safer (hence better) approach is to use mesomeric resonance formulae instead (and to recall that benzene isn't 1,3,6-cyclohexatriene with an alternating pattern of single and double bonds).

Comment: The Thiele ring is awfully small in the picture posted by the OP, and almost looks like an oxygen atom.

Comment: @Karsten, yes, it appears a craftsman without a technical background tried to copy the image. BTW, I've had difficulties getting a grave-stone properly engraved -- accuracy is not a priority for some commercial operations.

Comment: Probably the craftsman had observed that the whole image contains $4$ groups of $2$ capital letters with one number ($2$) in index. In three of these groups the index was at the end of the group. As it was not the case in the left group, he probably decided that the "internal index" was a mistake, that had to be corrected.